# Sign up feature throwing a 422 unprocessable entity error even though username and password are valid

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, error-handling, controller, fetch

I'm trying to create a sign up feature for my application but anytime I put a username and password that's valid it returns a 422 unprocessable entity error. When I use postman it works fine, I am able to add a new user. However when I use my application it does not work. I am using React frontend and Ruby backend.

SignUp Component

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState } from "react";

function SignUp({setCurrentUser}) {

    const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
    
    function handleSignUp(e) {
        e.preventDefault()

        const user = {
           username,
            password
        }

        fetch(`/users`,{
            method: "POST",
            header: {
                "Content-Type" : "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(user)
        }).then(r => {
            if(r.ok) {
                r.json().then(setCurrentUser)
            }})
    
    }



    return (
        <div>
         <form onSubmit={handleSignUp}>
            <p>Username</p>
            <input type="text" onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}/>
            <p>Password</p>
            <input type="text" onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}/>
            <button type="submit">Sign Up</button>
        </form>
        </div>
    );
}

export default SignUp;
```

UsersController

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    wrap_parameters format: []
    rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid, with: :record_invalid_response

    def index
        users = User.all
        render json: users
    end

    def create
        user = User.create!(user_params)
        render json: user, status: :created
    end

    def show
        user = User.find(session[:user_id])
        if user
            render json: user
        else
            render json: { error: "Not authorized" }, status: :unauthorized
        end
    end

    private

    def user_params
        params.permit(:username, :password)
        # :first_name, :last_name, :phone_number, :email
    end

    def record_invalid_response(invalid)
        render json: {error: invalid.record.errors.full_messages}, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end

end
```

Routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do


  post "/login", to: "sessions#create"
  delete "logout", to: "sessions#destroy"

  resources :users, only: [:index, :create, :show]


end
```

When I put a byebug in my controller and try to look at the user_params nothing shows. This is what I get from the server when I try to sign up a user from the frontend

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2022-11-13 14:00:10 -0500
Processing by UsersController#create as */*
Completed 400 Bad Request in 2ms (Allocations: 583)


  
ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: user
Did you mean?  controller
               action):
  
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:27:in `user_params'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:11:in `create'
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2022-11-13 14:04:13 -0500
Processing by UsersController#create as */*
  TRANSACTION (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/users_controller.rb:11:in `create'
  User Exists? (8.3ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."username" IS NULL LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/users_controller.rb:11:in `create'
  TRANSACTION (0.7ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/users_controller.rb:11:in `create'
[active_model_serializers] Rendered ActiveModel::Serializer::Null with Hash (0.19ms)
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 134ms (Views: 1.1ms | ActiveRecord: 58.1ms | Allocations: 11697)
```

I want to be able to sign up a user from the client's end. Thank You for all your help in advance!!

Comment: Is the body present in the dev tools?

Comment: Hi @KonradLinkowski thank you for answering! I apologize I'm not sure what you mean (I'm a beginner) but this is the error I'm receiving in the console as well SignUp.js:21          POST http://localhost:4000/users 422 (Unprocessable Entity)

Comment: Open dev tools in the browser and click network tab

Comment: The code here in the question isn't actually the same code thats running - if you look at the error message a `ActionController::ParameterMissing` exception is being raised which isn't actually possible if we take this code at face value. You need to enure that the code you think is running is actually running an eliminate any error sources like unsaved files or version control issues.

Comment: Beyond that there is some pretty wierd stuff in here. I'm not sure what `wrap_parameters format: []` is supposed to acheive - if you want to disable it just use `wrap_parameters false`.  In your `show` method `User.find(session[:user_id])` will raise an ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound exception so the following lines will never be reached if there is no user. Its also kind of wierd since the route is defined as `/users/:id`. If you want to define a route to show the currently signed in user I would either add a custom action like `/users/current` or a singular route.

Comment: To clarify on the first comment - somewhere in the code thats actually running you have `params.require(:user)` which is causing the exception.